# What should be the return type of property while assigning datasource to HTML select in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Please advise how I can assign datasource to HTML select control from code behind using a property in asp.net. I want to know what should be the type of property like will it be OBJECT

**HTML**

```
<select name="searchKey" id="selDropdown" runat="server"></select>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list items just like an asp Dropdown list, something like...

```
selDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "Value", true));
```

I am not sure, but have you tried this?

```
selDropdown.DataSourceID = "DatasourceID";
selDropdown.DataTextField = "";
selDropdown.DataValueField = "";
```

Comment: and what about first one, manually adding adding items through collection loop ?

Comment: but in code behind intellisense is there and I am able to access properties ?

Comment: I have tested the first option to add item, its working on my side. However I have not tested the second one.

Comment: Could you just test it at your end ?